# Working with SVG Path without SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, pixi.js

I have this generic SVG Path, consisting of quadratic curves. I don't need to draw it, I don't even have an SVG element, just the string with points (well, I do have a full SVG file if it matters). All I need is one simple thing: to get coordinates of a point on this path by given percent or length or any other way. `Path.pointAt()` will work perfectly.

Question is: what is the easiest and best performance-wise way to do it? Am I to create an SVG element and work with it dynamically via JS? Will it affect overall performance if I have, like, 10-30 of these paths?
Maybe there are any known libraries providing just the math? If it matters, I'm working with PixiJS v4, and my target platform is, well, all of them: desktop browsers (incl IE11), iOS and Android devices.

Comment: Why can't you use the curve formula?

Comment: I can. But my paths have a lot of these curves in them, so I would have to write my own library and do a lot of calculations. I actually have my own math for quadratic curves (converted from AS3 code), but trying to migrate to `SVG.Path` or some other lib: inventing a bicycle is not a proper way to do things in 2018.

Comment: [tag:paperjs] might be a good choice here, see for example [Path.getPointAt()](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getpointat-offset).

Comment: Have a look at [rveciana's "svg-path-properties"](https://github.com/rveciana/svg-path-properties). See also ["Opposite of svg's getPointAtLength(d) - I want getLengthAtPoint(x,y)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77985684/opposite-of-svgs-getpointatlengthd-i-want-getlengthatpointx-y/77990940#77990940)